# Moved CGI-Bin folder by mistake, now site won't work

Tags: webserver

I moved the CGI-Bin folder into a different folder by mistake using ftp, and when I moved it back my website stopped working.

Using CentOS6.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you moved it within a filesystem or to a different volume?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that their permissions and ownership are incorrect.  Log in with SSH and check to make sure they're executable and owned by the web server's user.  Also, you'll probably want to run `restorecon -r -v /path/to/cgi-bin` to make sure the directory and all its files have the correct SELinux attributes.